# How to pull specific value from list of dictionaries as the length/order of dictionaries change

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to collect data for all digital assets within a certain game. I'm pulling my data from this [API](https://api.opensea.io/asset/0x5d00d312e171be5342067c09bae883f9bcb2003b/1/) . The 1 at the end of the URL represents token_id = 1. My code will cycle through 1 to approx. 51,400 and collect the data that I need.

Three of the variables I'm looking at are "catch_number", "class_name", and "level". These all appear in their own dictionary under "traits", but depending on the token_id they appear in different orders.

See [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk4Yn.jpg) where the order and length differ for token_id's 1,7, & 9.

How can I pull the value for "trait_type": "class_name" (for example) no matter the order length of the list of dictionaries?

Since they appear in different orders, we can't use [0] - [4] to reference specific dictionaries.

And being that the length of the list of dictionaries changes, we can't use itemgetter to sort, which is what I tried most recently.

```
import json
import requests
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

result = {}
max_id_to_get = 25

for token_id in range(1,max_id_to_get):
    r = requests.get('https://api.opensea.io/asset/0x5d00d312e171be5342067c09bae883f9bcb2003b/{}'.format(token_id))
    EMONA_json = r.json()
    EMONA_str = json.dumps(EMONA_json, indent=2)

    traits = EMONA_json['traits']
    traits.sort(key=itemgetter('trait_type'))

    token_id = EMONA_json['token_id']
    name = (traits[2]['value'])
    level = (traits[3]['value'])
    catch_number = (traits[1]['value'])
    owner_address = EMONA_json['owner']['address']
    result[token_id] = {"name":name, "level":level, "catch_number":catch_number, "owner_address":owner_address}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(["token_id", "name", "level", "catch_number", "owner_address"])
    for id in result:
        writer.writerow([id, result[id]['name'], result[id]['level'], result[id]['catch_number'], result[id]['owner_address']])
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traits are given as a list of json objects with no deterministic order. The simplest solution for you would be to iterate over the trait list for each token and check if the `trait_type` is in the set of types you are interested in.

Sorting is not a good solution because if a new trait_type gets added, the order might change and the indexes 1,2,3 may no longer be referring to the traits you are interested in. In addition, sorting is slower than simply iterating the list.

Instead maintain a dictionary of trait_type to the trait dictionary so you can access it easily.

```py
for token_id in range(1,max_id_to_get):
    r = requests.get('https://api.opensea.io/asset/0x5d00d312e171be5342067c09bae883f9bcb2003b/{}'.format(token_id))
    EMONA_json = r.json()
    EMONA_str = json.dumps(EMONA_json, indent=2)

    interested_traits = ['catch_number', 'class_name', 'level']
    trait_dict = {}
    traits = EMONA_json['traits']
    for trait in traits:
        if trait['trait_type'] in interested_traits:
            trait_dict[trait['trait_type']] = trait

    token_id = EMONA_json['token_id']
    name = trait_dict['class_name']['value']
    level = trait_dict['level']['value']
    catch_number = trait_dict['catch_number']['value']
    owner_address = EMONA_json['owner']['address']
    result[token_id] = {"name":name, "level":level, "catch_number":catch_number, "owner_address":owner_address}
```